# Select from DB without some value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I have my own rails app and I need to specify what I want to get from DB (pg). Ordinary, we do it like that: `@posts = Post.all` and I will get all the post in my Post Table.

In Post Table I have a categories, as a boolean: (photo, video, etc.) and when I want to select only posts witch response to photo category, we do it like that: `@posts = Post.where(photo: true)`

But what I need, is to select all posts without, for example, video. It have to look something like that: `@posts = Post.all.without(video:true)`. How to make it happen?

*UPDATED*

And is there any possibility to block several values? I mean something like that `Post.where.not(id: 1 && 2)`. I really don't know how it must look like. What i need - is to select all Posts without posts with ID 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .not, for example

```
@posts = Post.where.not(video:true)
```

Comment: or @posts = Post.where(video: false)

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
@posts = Post.where.not(video: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of values: `Post.where.not(id: [1, 2])`